# Temporarily close my own challenge

Tags: support

I have a [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123520/68602) that I posted which I'd like to put on hold while I refine it in sandbox. Is this possible?

I don't want to delete it because I'd like to recycle bits of it, and I'm guessing if it's deleted then I'll lose the work I've done/ there will be a time limit on how long I can still access it.

What can I do to make the challenge invisible to site users/ clearly not currently "open". Is there some way of closing it myself, or if not can people reading this please vote to close as suggested [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12166/68602)?

Also, I intend to re-post after refinement as a different question and delete the original (is this acceptable?)

Answer (score 4):

You can still access the challenge when it's deleted (and there's no time limit for how long you can access it). You can even edit it while it's deleted and then undelete it once the challenge has been improved with feedback from the sandbox.

Whether reposting is acceptable depends a lot on how substantial the changes from the sandbox are. I'd say if you thoroughly overhaul and improve the challenge, no one will mind if you post the new version separately, but if it's just some minor cosmetic changes, then posting a new one seems like a way to clear the downvotes and close votes on the challenge, which is certainly frowned upon. There is no clear objective line we can draw here, so just use your best judgement.

Comment: I don't think you edit a question when it's been deleted... I tried recently

Comment: Just to add to this. If you can't remove it mods can help by removing the challenge for you and you can ask to get it undeleated when it is ready